# Несколько видео на одной интернет-страничке

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, что сделать, чтобы имеющийся [на сайте](http://симультики.рф) скрипт обслуживал бы (если так можно сказать) несколько разных видео? Чтобы я мог с разных ссылок выводить разные видео. Я лишь могу, не имея знаний по яваскрипту, продублировать данный скрипт два раза, но думаю, что было бы явно лишним. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот часть вашего кода:

```
<video width=420 controls>
    <source src="Simovie1.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="Simovie1.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

На сайте вы используете jQuery. По какому-то событию, вы можете свободно менять путь к новому ролику в атрибуте src. Предположим, что событие - это клик на превьюшке мультика который будет в блоке <div class="preview">, кроме этого, добавим какой-нибудь атрибут, значение которого - это и будет имя нужного ролика: <div class="preview" rel="Simovie555">. В jQuery делаем таким образом:

```
$('.preview').click(function(){
    var pV = $('video source');
    var mName = $(this).attr('rel');
    pV.eq(0).attr('src', mName + '.mp4');
    pV.eq(1).attr('src', mName + '.webm');
});
```

Всё зависит от конкретных задач, но суть, я надеюсь, что вы уловили

Comment: Про src это я понимаю, но если я дублирую тот же самый код с видео в какое-то другое место, чтобы там было еще одно видео, скрипт берет то видео которое находит первым по коду и воспроизводит только его, а второе вообще никак не воспроизводиться, вот в чем проблема. Я так понял, что скрипт ищет id="popup__toggle" и другие соотв. айдишки, вот что с этим сделать? В голову приходит только один способ - продублировать скрипт, поменяв айдишки, но разве это разумно?..

Comment: А изменить id-шник на класс вот тут:

    <input type="button" value="Смотри!" class="popup__toggle" />

И соответственно обращаться по классу

    $('.popup__toggle').click(function() {
        p.css('display', 'block')
    });

Comment: Получается следующее. По обеим кнопкам теперь открывается видеоокно, но видео проигрывается одно и то же, хотя в src я проставил разные файлы...